# How can I add a default alternative spelling to voice dictation?

Tags: voice-recognition

My SO has a different spelling (but same pronounciation) of a common name. Every time I use voice dictation (which is all the time) and I say their name, I have to correct it with the keyboard. Is there a way to switch it to use the "correct" spelling by default? I am on Android 11

Comment: Sorry I  posted a near duplicate of your question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/243090/12202  same question but for Android 12.